# Data PreProcessing for BERT (base-german)

Tags: deep-learning, nlp, data-cleaning, bert-language-model

I am working on a sentiment analysis solution with BERT to analyze tweets in german. My training dataset of is a class of 1000 tweets, which have been manually annotated into the classes neutral, positive and negative.

The dataset with 10.000 tweets is quite unevenly distributed:

approx.
3000 positive
2000 negative
5000 neutral

the tweets contain formulations with @names, https links, numbers, punctuation marks, smileys like :3 :D :) etc..

The interesting thing is, if I remove them with the following code during Data Cleaning, the F1 score gets worse. Only the removal of https links (if I do it alone) leads to a small improvement.

```
# removing the punctuation and numbers
def remove_punct(text):
    text = re.sub(r'http\S+', '', text)                                         # removing links
    text = re.sub(r'@\S+', '', text)                                            # removing referencing on usernames with @
    text = re.sub(r':\S+', '', text)                                            # removing smileys with : (like :),:D,:( etc) 
    text  = "".join([char for char in text if char not in string.punctuation])
    text = re.sub('[0-9]+', '', text)
    return text

data['Tweet_clean'] = data['Tweet'].apply(lambda x: remove_punct(x))            # extending the dataset with the column tweet_clean
data.head(40)
```

also steps like stop words removal or lemmitazation lead more to a deterioration. Is this because I do something wrong or can the model BERT actually handle such values?

A second question is:

I found other records that were also manually annotated, but these are not tweets and the structure of the sentences and language use is different. Would you still recommend to add these records to my original?

There are about 3000 records in German.

My last question:

Should I reduce the class sizes to the size of the smallest unit and thus balance?

Answer (score 3):

1. BERT can handle punctuation, smileys etc. Of course, smileys contribute a lot to sentiment analysis. So, don't remove them. Next, it would be fair to replace @mentions and links with some special tokens, because the model will probably never see them again in the future.
2. If your model is designed for tweets, I suggest that you fine-tune BERT with additional corpus, and after fine-tune with Twitter corpus. Or do it simultaneously. More training samples is generally better.
3. No, it is better to use class weights instead of downsampling.

Comment: Although I'm new to BERT, I'm not sure if it detects smiley faces. You can test it using HuggingFace's API for [distilbert-base-uncased-finetuned-sst-2-english](https://huggingface.co/distilbert-base-uncased-finetuned-sst-2-english), It didn't made much difference on my tests at least.

Comment: @keivanIpchi try `AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained('your-config').tokenize(':) :D')`. You'll probably see that the smileys are split into pieces, and not replaced with the [UNK] token.

Answer (score 1):

Based on [this](https://aclanthology.org/2020.pam-1.15.pdf) paper (By *Adam Ek, Jean-Philippe Bernardy and Stergios Chatzikyriakidis*), BERT models outperform BiLSTM in terms of better generalizing to punctuations. Looking at the experiments' results in the paper, I say keep the punctuations.

I couln't find anything solid for smiley faces; However, after doing some experiments with the HuggingFace API, I didn't notice much difference with/without smiley faces.